# How to pass parameters to conditional function types

Tags: typescript

The following is a very simple representation of the issue I'm running into.

```
function func1(arg1: string) {
  return arg1
}

function func2(arg1: number, arg2: string) {
  return arg2
}

function selector<Determiner extends boolean>(
  useFunc1Type: Determiner,
  func: Determiner extends true ? typeof func1 : typeof func2
) {
  if (useFunc1Type) {
    func() // arg1 is inferred as 'never', shouldn't it be 'string'
  }
}
```

I need to call func with appropriate parameters depending on the value of `useFunc1Type`, but I can't get the compiler to narrow down the type of `func`. It keeps inferring the first argument as 'never' since there's no overlap between the types of the first parameters of the two functions (`string` and `number`). I thought using an `if` block would do the trick, but it isn't. What can I do in this case?

I'm using TypeScript v5.1.6 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like despite being at V5, Typescript still has huge issues with type inference. I had to split up into overloads and use a type guard.

```
function func1(arg1: string) {
  return arg1
}

function func2(arg1: number, arg2: string) {
  return arg2
}

function selector(useFunc1Type: true, func: typeof func1): void;
function selector(useFunc1Type: false, func: typeof func2): void;

function selector(
  useFunc1Type: boolean,
  func: typeof func1 | typeof func2
): void {
  const isFunc1 = (fn: typeof func): fn is typeof func1 => useFunc1Type;

  if (isFunc1(func)) {
    func("properly 'inferred'");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My use case is somewhat more complex, but the trick works, and I've just applied it. We'l have to wait for typescript to fill these gaps.